# Writing multiple strings into a variable (Python)

Tags: python, lan, netsh

I am trying to make a Python NetSH network maker using Python and the Tkinter Module, I am currently stuck on how to combine an entry when making the final Batch document that the program will execute. Please refer to the start of the 'e1' section to understand my problem.

My aim is to take both entries from the user and write them to a batch file to make a wlan network using the computer's network card. I also have tried referencing the variables separately which has also given errors.

```
#Simple GUI
#Import Tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen

#Window
master = Tk()

#Modify Root Window
master.title("Simple GUI")
master.geometry("640x420")

Label(master, text="Network Name").grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(master, text="Network Password").grid(row=4, column=0)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=1, column=0)
e2.grid(row=5, column=0)

e3 = (e1, " key=", e2)

# Secondary Window
def success():
   tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Success", "WiFi Network created!\n\nThe Wifi 
Network will end once the computer is restarted or shut down")

#CMD Command
def run():
    text_file = open("wifi.txt", "w")
    text_file.write("netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=")
    text_file.write(e3)
    text_file.write("\nnetsh wlan start hostednetwork")
    text_file.close()



Button(master, text='Generate', command = run).grid(row=6, column=0, 
sticky=N, pady=2)


#Making a label
master = Frame(master)
master.grid()
label2 = Label(master, text = "This is a baisc Python program using the 
Tkinter GUI interface \n to successfully execute bash code in the Command 
Prompt to make a WiFi Network using your laptop's Network Card.")
label2.grid(row=10, column=0)

#Button 'Help'
def info():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo()
B1 = tkinter.Button(master, text ="info", relief=RAISED,\
                         bitmap="info")
B1.grid()



#Text Writing
def writeFile():
    file = open('command.bat')
    file.write(metinF.get() + '\n')
    file.close()


'''
#Button
button1 = Button(app, text = "Generate")
button1.grid()

button2 = Button(app)
button2.grid()

button2.configure(text = "Decline")

button3 = Button(app)
button3.grid()

button3["text"] = "Help"
'''

#Label 2
app = Frame(master)
app.grid()
label2 = Label(app, text = "\n Made by Christopher Grainger \n 2018")
label2.grid()

#Kick Event
master.mainloop()
```

Please help as this error is extremely confusing and not even Google has any valid solutions for this. I've tried things listed online but they also have their own errors.

Thanks;

Chris
appleosophy.com
@appleosophy

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: `Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "E:\Python\Network Maker\netsh.py", line 35, in run
        text_file.write(e3)
    TypeError: must be str, not tuple`

Comment: e3 is a tuple and you passing it on to write function which accepts argument in string.What's so confusing in that?

Comment: The write function isn't accepting either declaring the variables separately or in a tuple. I am just confused on how I can get it written to the batch file.

Comment: Case I've also tried:

`#CMD Command
def run():
    text_file = open("wifi.txt", "w")
    text_file.write("netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=")
    text_file.write(e1)
    text_file.write(" key=")
    text_file.write(e2)
    text_file.write("\nnetsh wlan start hostednetwork")
    text_file.close()`

Comment: e3 = e1.get()+ " key="+e2.get()

Comment: Okay, I'll try that then. I've got to go off to a different lesson now, so I'll do it when I get home. Thanks a lot; Sreyas

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write a tuple into a file.But write method only takes string as argument. Use

```
e3 = e1.get() + " =key" +e2.get()
```

inside your run function.

Get method returns the input in the entry as string.

Comment: This worked, I have now completed my program!! Thanks so much